# MATLAB sprintf from two arrays

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

Say I have the following two arrays

```
x=[1 2 3 4 5 ];
y=[3 8 9 12 44];
```

Now I wish to create a string from them using sprintf that will display it to me as follows:

```
x1 = 3
x2 = 8
x3 = 9
x4 = 12
x5 = 44
```

But I am unable to get it to work correctly. This is what I currently have (I know it might be very wrong since I have been playing around with the code quite a lot and might have messed it up even more in the process)

```
str = '';
for ii = 1:length(x)
    str = sprintf('x%d= %d \n',x,y)
end
str
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost got it right. There is no need for a for loop:

```
sprintf('x%d = %d\n',[x;y])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `arrayfun` for `cell` array as output -

```
arrayfun(@(n) ['x' num2str(x(n)) ' = ' num2str(y(n))],1:numel(x),'Uni',0).'
```

Code run -

```
ans = 
    'x1 = 3'
    'x2 = 8'
    'x3 = 9'
    'x4 = 12'
    'x5 = 44'
```

If you would like to have a `char` array as output, wrap it with `char()`, giving us -

```
ans =
x1 = 3 
x2 = 8 
x3 = 9 
x4 = 12
x5 = 44
```

Comment: I think that there are easier ways than this.

Answer (score 3):

The `sprintf` function does not have the behavior that you expect for vectors. The function actually looks at each element. Notice that the specifier %d is an int and not an in vector. This means that for your function call, `sprintf` see something equivalent to the vector `[x,y]`. However, when the function looks up elements, it is done per column. So there are two solutions.

1) Use subindexing for the elements (not recommended). This also does not repeat the same function call 5 times.

```
str = {};
for ii = 1:length(x)
    str{ii} = sprintf('x%d= %d \n',x(ii),y(ii));
end
str
```

This will actually give you a cell and generating a matrix for this would be annoying

2) Use a vectorized input (recommended). Since `sprintf` reads matrices columnwise, you can use a properly formatted matrix.

```
str = sprintf('x%-2d = %d \n',[x;y])
```

Comment: Are you sure the second solution is what the OP is after? I ran it and I got `str= x=3 ...` etc. It has the word str in the output.

Comment: @kkuilla - his second one only needed [x;y] instead of x,y. It when runs perfectly :)

Comment: @kkuilla I am not sure how you got this, you should try again. According to the question OP want to save the string to a variable `str`. If OP wants a printout it is just to change the function to `fprintf`.

Comment: @Dillon sorry, just a typo. Good that you saw it.

Comment: @Dillon Many people do not look at questions with an accepted answer. I think it would be good to leave it open for, let's say a day, so that the answers can gain more votes and the posters get more value for their efforts..